# Hi all, I want to develop navigation app in using Xamarin forms. What I can use?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, maps, live

I want to develop navigation app[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4VIq.png) in using Xamarin forms. What I can use? I'm open to use any Xamarin.Forms.map or  Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMap. It should let me know distance and time required. Please find attached screen shot.

Comment: Hello, Jitendra welcome to stack overflow, I would like to see what have you done so far, have you written any code for the same?

Comment: Yes, I have used Xamarin.Forms.map and using google direction API is I'm drawing route on map. I 'm using API key also but still routes are not getting drawing as expected. There is no problem in drawing Logic. I'm thinking that there is something wrong I'm getting in direction API.

Comment: Show us your code then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have did this. Using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMap and Google direction API. Created poly line using coordinates received from Google direction API. Google direction API contains encoded "polyline". We have to decode "polyline" and then we got Positions. Using that positions we can create polyline and google map will draw that polyline itself. Google map is having property polylines(its a list) in which we have add newly created polyline. Thanks to Google.